# Numbers n such that sigma(F(n)) > 2*F(n) where F(n) is the n-th Fibonacci number

Tags: numbers, fibonacci

Sorry to be so dumb, but in layman's terms with possible simple examples can someone explain how this works?

> Numbers n such that sigma(F(n)) > 2*F(n) where F(n) is the n-th
>   Fibonacci number.

Comment: Sorry also that produce the numbers - 12,18,24,30,36,40,42,48,54,60,72,80,84,90,96,108,120,126,132,140,144, 

%T 150,156,160,162,168,180,192,198,200,204,210,216,225,228,234,240,252, 

%U 264,270,276,280,288,294,300,306,312,315,320

Comment: Please explain how is this a programming problem?

Comment: It's not really, but the equation will be transferred into code.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please give the  background to this request. To me it looks like a homework assignment (if yes: then you should clarify with lecturer and fellow students)